# Create array of objects C++

Tags: c++, class, object

I am trying to create an array of objects of my class in c++. When I print the objects, it skips the first element of array (a[0]). I have read many forums, but I can't find the problem. Who can see it?

```
class driver
{
private:
    string name;
    string surname;
    string categories;
    int salary, hours;   
public: 
void reads(string &n, string &p, string &c, int &s, int &h)
{
    std::cout<<"\t\t Give information about driver:"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"\t\t---------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout<<"\tGive name: "; std::cin>>n;
    std::cout<<"\tGive surname: "; std::cin>>p;
    std::cout<<"\tGive categories of driver license: "; std::cin>>c;
    std::cout<<"\tHow much he is payd for hour: "; std::cin>>s;
    std::cout<<"\tHow many hours did "<<n<<" "<<p<<" works? "; std::cin>>h;
} 
void print()
{
    std::cout<<name<<" "<<surname<<" ";
    std::cout<<"has categories "<<categories<<endl;
    std::cout<<"Salary per hour is "<<salary<<endl;
    std::cout<<"Driver had worked "<<hours<<" hours"<<endl;
    std::cout<<"Full payment is "<<salariu*hlucru<<" $"<<endl;
}
};
int main()
{
   string n,p,c;
   int s,h,nr,i;
 cout<<"Give nr of drivers:"; cin>>nr;
 driver *a[nr];
 for(i=0;i<nr;i++)
 {
     a[i]=new driver(n,p,c,s,h);
     a[i]->reads(n,p,c,s,h);
     cout<<endl;
 }
 for(i=0;i<nr;i++)
 {
     a[i]->print();
     cout<<endl;
 }
```

Comment: Your `reads()` function doesn't change any single object in `driver` class. You change your strings in `main`, and then you pass these strings to the next object. Your first `driver` object has uninitialized fields.

Comment: `driver *a[nr]` is invalid C++ as it uses VLA extension. use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: driver constructor is missing btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `reads()` function is not doing what you expect. It's reading data to your `main()` strings, and then you pass these strings to the next object you create.
Your `a[0]` have uninitialized members, this is what you see as "not printing a[0]"

Your code probably should look more like this:

```
void reads() {
    //all the std::cout calls should also be here
    std::cin >> name;
    std::cin >> surname; //etc. 
}
```

In your `main()`:

```
int main()
{
    int nr;
    cout << "Give nr of drivers:"; 
    cin >> nr;
    driver* a = new driver[nr]; //use std::vector instead!
    for(int i = 0; i < nr; i++)
    {
        a[i].reads();
        cout<<endl;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < nr; i++)
    {
        a[i].print();
        cout<<endl;
    }
    delete[] a;
}
```